# UILabel Updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm just updating the UILabel, code is

```
-(void)updateUI
{
    _syncCountLbl.text=[Global retrieveFromUserDefaults:@"dbCountKey"]
    if ([_syncCountLbl.text isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        [_syncCountLbl setHidden:YES];
    }
    else
        [_syncCountLbl setHidden:NO];
}
```

I'm calling this method when

In the console it is showing the text, but not updating in UI.

```
UILabel: 0x166c9900; frame = (39 0; 23 22); text = '3'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x166c99a0
```

Comment: Please complete your question, fill it out with more code

Comment: What's your issue. When is this code called? What are you expecting?

Comment: try using `_syncCountLbl.alpha = 0;` instead.

Comment: its in the method, am calling the method whenever i needed.i'll edit with complete code

Comment: Please share more code

Comment: Code is irrelevant. As Larme said, what are you expecting ? What is happening ?

Comment: That can't be the code, it won't compile, there is no `;` at the end of the first statement. Could you post your actual code?

Comment: Is your UILabel instantiated in code or SB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling your `updateUI` method from a tread *other than the main thread*, the UI is not guaranteed to update immediately. It can happen in 20 seconds, 45 seconds or never, depending when the next UI element requests the UI to update.

Try dispatching to the main thread before calling any UIKit code:

```
-(void)updateUI
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _syncCountLbl.text=[Global retrieveFromUserDefaults:@"dbCountKey"]
        if ([_syncCountLbl.text isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
            [_syncCountLbl setHidden:YES];
        }
        else
            [_syncCountLbl setHidden:NO];
    });
}
```